# i get sql syntax error and dint match any of suggested answer

Tags: php, cakephp

Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''dashboards' (employ_id,system_id,on-time,off-time,is_active) values ('Array' at line 1

```
public function admin_dashboard($id=null) {
        $this->loadModel('Employ','System');
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            //debug($this->request->data);exit;
            $employId = $this->request->data['Dashboard']['employ_id'];
            $systemId = $this->request->data['Dashboard']['system_id'];
            $logon = $this->request->data['Dashboard']['on-time'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $logout = $this->request->data['Dashboard']['off-time'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $active = $this->request->data['Dashboard']['is_active'];

            //$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            for($i=0;$i<count ($systemId);$i++){


            $this->System->query("insert into 'dashboards' (employ_id,system_id,on-time,off-time,is_active) values              ('$employId','$systemId[$i]','$logon','$logout','$active')");
            //$var_dump($date);
            }

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The query has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'admin_dashboard'));

        }/* else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The query could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }*/
        $employs = $this->Employ->find('list');
        $systems = $this->System->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('employs','systems'));
    }
```

Comment: remove quotes from 'dashboard'

Comment: Why are you using `query` at all?

Comment: without using query how can i insert the value to the dashboard which is dependent in system controller. if u can den do suugest me alternative

Comment: Vickrant tried ur way too bt it dont fetch the input at all

Comment: Looks like you should really read the basics about [CakePHP 2 model layer](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html).

Comment: @ AD7six there is no Dashboard model created coz it dont have primary key its dependent on employ and system

Comment: That doesn't change my answer @PrabeenKumar, you don't need for the model file to exist to use it - and there being no primary key (while generally speaking being a bad idea) shouldn't prevent inserts.

Answer (score 1):

### The MySQL identifier quote character is the backtick

The first error in the question is because the [quote character of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) is the backtick not a single quote.

i.e. valid:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `select` WHERE `select`.id > 100;
```

Invalid:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM 'select' WHERE 'select'.id > 100;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''select' WHERE 'select'.id > 100' at line 1
mysql>
```

There are literally [thousands of similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql%20the%20right%20syntax%20to%20use%20near) on stack overflow, as it's a common mistake.

### There is no need to use query

However that's not the biggest problem/mistake in the question code. [Model::query](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query) is designed/expected to be used for:

> SQL calls that you can’t or don’t want to make via other model methods

Inserting data into the db does not fall into that category; Effectively it should be used as a last resort (generally speaking it is very rare to *need* to use this method).

Something similar to this is all that's required:

```
$this->loadModel('Dashboard');
$data = [];
foreach ($this->request->data['Dashboard']['system_id'] as $systemId) {
    $row = $this->request->data['Dashboard'];
    $row['system_id'] = $systemId;
    $data[] = $row;
}
$this->Dashboard->saveMany($data);
```

[saveMany](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array) is one of the [standard ways to save data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html), and the most appropriate given the info in the question.

Note that if the logic is any more than a few lines of code it should not be in a controller action at all, and moved to the model instead e.g.:

```
// in controller
$this->Dashboard->myMethod($data);

// in the Dashboard class:
public function myMethod($input)
{
    ... whatever is necessary ...
    return $this->saveMany($data);
}
```